# how to call encrypted Password PHP to Android Mysql

Tags: php, password-hash

my login activity cannot read encrypted Password i tried without encrypted password and it works and im not sure if the error from php or activity itself of how to decryption password

> im Using PASSWORD_BCRYPT

---

```
   <?php
     include "conn.php";



     $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];


    $sql_login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = :EMAIL and Password =:PASSWORD";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_login);
    $stmt->bindParam(':EMAIL', $Email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':PASSWORD', $Password);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

    $returnApp = array('LOGIN' => 'SUCCESS');

    echo json_encode($returnApp);

    }else{

    $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'FAILED');

    echo json_encode($returnApp);

    }



    ?>
```

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Android?

Comment: im trying to call the password to login and it says wrong password

Comment: The code above works with unencrypted passwords. Which is Very Bad™. Encrypted passwords by the way are Also Bad™. Use a hash and salt or another provider. Look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: thanks alot i will take a look at it

Comment: Make the email address `UNIQUE` match on that to retrieve the password. I assume you're already using [password_hash](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) since you state *"im Using PASSWORD_BCRYPT"*, so you should be using `password_verify()` to validate the POSTed password against the hash retrieved from the database... not trying to mung it straight into the SQL query.

Comment: @BartFriederichs do you have any tutorial of how to use hash and salt

Comment: No, but it should be easy enough to Google.

Comment: @BartFriederichs yeah i know .. i found out to many methods of how to use it and some commented on them for weak so i was only checking for a good one.. thanks a lot for the advice to use hash and salt

Comment: Also, you say you are using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, but your code doesn't show that. The documentation on PHP's [`password_hash`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function gives quite some info on how to use it. In short, you hash the password, store the hash. Then, when trying to match, you use [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check if the sent password was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly use hashing of a password in PHP, use the [`password_hash`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) combination.

When a user signs up, you get his password, hash it and store it in the database:

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST['newpassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// store $hash in database column "password"
```

When this user wants to login, you check against the hash:

```
// fetch hash from database, store it in $stored_hash
$logged_in = password_verify($_POST['password'], $stored_hash);
if ($logged_in === TRUE) {
    echo "Welcome!";
} else {
    echo "Username or password incorrect.";
}
```

Final notes:

1. Use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` and make sure your database can store the result (also in the future). Hashing algorithms happen to get cracked once in a while.
2. You could use another provider like Google or Facebook to handle your authentication. This does have its drawbacks as well though.